# What is the difference between passing It.IsAny<int>() and the value of It.IsAny<int>() to a method setup

Tags: c#, moq

I'm using Moq and want to create builder classes to create my mocks with preset reasonable defaults that can be overridden during test setup as needed. The approach I took uses extension methods in which I pass input parameter values and expected output. In doing so, I'm seeing different behavior in what seems to me to be semantically equivalent code: passing It.IsAny() directly in a setup vs passing the value of It.IsAny() indirectly in a setup. Example:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    bool Bar(int value);
    bool Bar2(int value);
}
public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public bool Bar(int value) { return false; }
    public bool Bar2(int value) { return false; }
}

var mock = new Mock<IFoo>();
mock.Setup(x => x.Bar(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(true);
Assert.IsTrue(mock.Object.Bar(123));                    // Succeeds

var myValue = It.IsAny<int>();
mock.Setup(x => x.Bar2(myValue)).Returns(true);
Assert.IsTrue(mock.Object.Bar2(123));                   // Fails
```

Both calls are equivalent (to me), yet the call to Bar2 fails assertion. Why is this?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`It.IsAny` only allows Moq to match future invocations of method calls if used within the `Setup` construct.  When `Setup` is called Moq just adds the method call to its cache of already-set-up method calls.  Note that the argument to `Setup` in your example has type `Expression<Func<IFoo, bool>>`.  Since you are passing in an `Expression`, the actual method call is not invoked and Moq has the ability to traverse the expression to figure out which parameters of the method call were explicit, and which are `It.IsAny` arguments.  It uses this ability to determine if a future method call at runtime matches one of the already-set-up method calls.

In order to make it so that the method `Bar` can accept argument `It.IsAny<int>()`, it is necessary to make `It.IsAny<int>()` return an `int` (since that is the type of the parameter of `Bar`).  In general, the return type of `It.IsAny<T>` must be `T`.  An arbitrary value of `T` must be chosen.  The most natural choice is `default(T)`, which works for reference types and value types.  (Read more about the default keyword [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)).  In your case, that is `default(int)`, which is `0`.

So when you actually evaluate `It.IsAny<int>()` the value of `0` is immediately returned.  However, when you use `It.IsAny<int>()` in an `Expression` (as in the argument to the `Setup` method), then the tree structure of the method call is preserved and Moq can match future method invocations to the method call encapsulated by the `Expression`.

So, although you cannot keep `It.IsAny<int>()` as a variable in any meaningful way, you can keep the entire `Expression` in a variable:

```
Expression<Func<IFoo, bool>> myExpr = x => x.Bar2(It.IsAny<int>());
mock.Setup(myExpr).Returns(true);
Assert.IsTrue(mock.Object.Bar2(123));
```

Finally, I just want to remind you that Moq is open source.  The source is available [here](https://code.google.com/p/moq/source/checkout).  I find it valuable to have that source code so that I can click around and explore the code and the unit tests.

Comment: Excellent explanation, Ben. I had a suspicion the issue lie in the expression evaluation, as you describe, rather than the return value of It.IsAny<int>(). I looked at the reflected source in ILSpy and could see It.IsAny<TValue>, but couldn't get my head wrapped around how it worked in regard to the problem.

Thanks again for the explanation.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up that witchcraft for me!  I was trying to say "var anyFooParam = It.IsAny<string>(); var anyBarParam = It.IsAny<string>();"  to see if it would make my tests more readable like: .Setup(mock => mock.method(anyFooParam, anyBarParam)).Returns(something!)

Answer (score 1):

`It.IsAny<int>()` has return type of int and returns `0`, so your second setup is equivalent to:

```
mock.Setup(x => x.Bar2(0)).Returns(true);
```

I didn't check the moq code, but I'm pretty sure that when it evaluates the expression in the setup method, it takes into account that the parameter is actually It.IsAny vs. a normal number.

You are better off if you create the setups directly in your helper methods, and not pass It.IsAny.