# Moq Setup: ability to pass a value or It.IsAny<T>() depending on condition

Tags: c#, moq

[The question is similar to this: [What is the difference between passing It.IsAny<int>() and the value of It.IsAny<int>() to a method setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17053064/what-is-the-difference-between-passing-it-isanyint-and-the-value-of-it-isany) - needing additional clarification]

### Short version

(More definitions below)

I am in a situation where **I need to setup mocks in a factory**. Depending on the value, I want to **choose between** using it or `It.IsAny<TTypeOfValue>()`.

This is what I (naively) wanted to do:

```
moq.Setup(() => mockWebService.WebServiceMethod(
    webServiceMethodObject.Some ?? It.IsAny<string>(), // that fails
    ...,
    out webServiceMethodObject.That,
    ...)).Returns(webServiceMethodObject.ReturnEnum);
```

I have such large parameterlists (old legacy webservice methods) and so much different combination of values that I don't want to write it by hand, nor using `It.IsAny<T>()` everywhere, as I want to control the return value depending on parameters.

A possible alternative should be the version, where I could match concrete values with concrete return types, and when no concrete values can be matched, it falls back to the broadest version (with all parameters substituted with `It.IsAny<T>()`. (Short example: in a login test I'd like to test different return values of different input parameters of a login method. In all other tests I'd just like to return LoginSuccess).

How can I achieve this? Only with some Expression/Reflection magic?

---

### Longer explanation

This is how our typical legacy webservice looks like:

```
ReturnValueEnum WebServiceMethod(string some, int thing, ..., out int that, out byte[] those, ...) { ... }
```

We had so many webservice method calls needed and they are so bloated with parameters, that we had to come up with encapsulating them in objects.
Example:

```
public class WebServiceMethodObject
{
    public string Some { get; set; }
    public int Thing { get; set; }
    ...
    public ReturnValue ReturnEnum { get; set; }
}
```

**The strategy should be this:** we are creating a default version of this object. In the tests we fill up values that needed to be matched. We would like to pass the object to a to-be-written method, which sets up the mock accordingly:

**if a property is set:** use that value

**else:** use `It.IsAny<T>()` (see the Setup above!).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would've thought that if

```
webServiceMethodObject.Some ?? It.IsAny<string>()
```

is what you want but doesn't work, the simple substitution would be

```
It.Is<string>(v =>
    webServiceMethodObject.Some == null ||
    webServiceMethodObject.Some == v)
```

Comment: +1: Slick way to achieve the same (as long as the logic only comes down to the `null` check)!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I never thought it will be that easy! (I think we'll probably be using Option type for reference types instead of null checks, as it is clearer to everybody.)

Answer (score 3):

If the logic for the parameters is so complex you can safely use `It.IsAny<T>` for all parameters and define a custom delegate to process the method call:

```
moq
    .Setup(() => WebServiceMethod(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<int>(), ...))
    .Returns((some, thing, ...) => {
        if (some == webServiceMethodObject.Some || webServiceMethodObject.Some == null) ...
        {
            return webServiceMethodObject.ReturnEnum;
        }
    });
```

If you look into the list of `Returns` overloads you see that there is a wealth of options, the "hardcoded" `.Returns(some value)` being only one of those.

As far as I know the the whole thing passed to setup is an expression tree. Moq then inspects the expression subtrees for the parameters. If they are `It` based expressions they are used for advanced logic. If not they are evaluated and the value is matched with the input. This is probably the/one reason why your naïve version is not working.