# Assign It.IsAny<> to local var does not work?

Tags: c#, tdd, moq

I thought to make my unit test code slightly more readable by assigning `It.IsAny<IWhatever>` to a local variable, and got surprised by the fact that my mock will not recognize the method call.

This works

```
rotationStrategyMock.
    Setup(rotateStrategy => rotateStrategy.IsRotationRequired(It.IsAny<IProduct>(), null)).
    Returns(true);
```

When I rewrite it as follows (extract `It.IsAny` to local var)

```
var anyProduct = It.IsAny<IProduct>();
rotationStrategyMock.
    Setup(rotateStrategy => rotateStrategy.IsRotationRequired(anyProduct, null)).
    Returns(true);
```

Then the mock returns false, because the method call is not recognized.

Can anybody explain why the second option does not work?

Comment: That is curious. I'm not sure why it doesn't work, but I don't find it to be that much more readable. In my experience, you will be writing so many mock setup statements that you'll become comfortable with the syntax and get tired of extracting everything to local variables.

Comment: @RyanBurbidge Yeah I must agree, I was actually trying this for another case of `It.IsAny<Action<IEnumerable<IInput>, long, string>>()`, but thought for the sake of the question to use a simpler example. But nonetheless, I agree and I think it's time to get used to the (for me) somewhat verbose syntax. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Setup` method is accepting an `Expression`, which is basically an uncompiled `Func`. The key here is "uncompiled."

When you pass `It.IsAny<T>()` into the Setup method directly, that object it generates remains uncompiled until runtime. However, by instantiating it first as a seperate step, the object passed into `Setup` is a concrete instance. Now, no arbitrary `Product` will pass the test, only that concrete isntance. You can see this in the following code:

```
public interface ITest
{
    bool IsTrue(int i);
}

public static TestClass
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var isAny = It.IsAny<int>();
        var tester = new Mock<ITest>();
        tester.Setup(t => t.IsTrue(isAny)).Returns(true);
        Console.WriteLine(tester.Object.IsTrue(1));     //false
        Console.WriteLine(tester.Object.IsTrue(isAny)); //true
    }
}
```

There's also a [more in-depth answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17053064/what-is-the-difference-between-passing-it-isanyint-and-the-value-of-it-isany)

Comment: And once again I failed to google properly to find the answer in a different thread... Thx for explaining and the ref to the Q&A