# Mocking + Issue with capturing return value of a method in c#

Tags: c#, mocking

I need to mock a method as well as its return value which is an object. Below is my code in the main class

```
//**Main Class**
var message = CorrelationMessageClient.GetCorrelationMessage(
      orderRequest.OrderId, CorrelationMessageType.CorrelationFix);
if (message != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(message.CorrelationId))
{
        sendOrderResponse = PrepareExecutionReport(
                 new MessageManager(message.ResponseMessage));
}
```

The return type of CorrelationMessageClient.GetCorrelationMessage is of the type  CorrelationMessage object.

In my unit test I have mocked as follows

```
//**Unit Test class** 
private Mock<ICorrelationMessageClient> _mockCorrelationMessageClient;
_mockCorrelationMessageClient = new Mock<ICorrelationMessageClient>();

var correlationResponse = new CorrelationMessage { 
    CorrelationId = "1212121",ResponseMessage = "Response Successful"};

_mockCorrelationMessageClient.Setup(x => 
    x.GetCorrelationMessage(correlationMessageFix.CorrelationId, 
      correlationMessageFix.CorrelationMessageType))
      .Returns(correlationResponse);
```

When I debug the Main Class code , I see that the values being passed to the GetCorrelationMessage method but the message variable remains null. Why is it null when I have written a Return statement in the setup method below

```
_mockCorrelationMessageClient.Setup(x =>
   x.GetCorrelationMessage(correlationMessageFix.CorrelationId, 
        correlationMessageFix.CorrelationMessageType))
       .Returns(correlationResponse);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using Moq. In this case methods' arguments of actual call need to match once that you use in the `.Setup` method, or you can allow any/particular matching function. I.e. `It.IsAny<T>` allows all value for particular argument:

```
_mockCorrelationMessageClient.Setup(x =>
   x.GetCorrelationMessage(It.IsAny<TypOfId>(), It.IsAny<TypeOfMessageType>()))
   .Returns(correlationResponse);
```

Otherwise you get default implementation of method that will return default value for result type (null for reference types).

Note that your should  have call to `It.IsAny` inline in `.Setup` - [What is the difference between passing It.IsAny<int>() and the value of It.IsAny<int>() to a method setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17053064/what-is-the-difference-between-passing-it-isanyint-and-the-value-of-it-isany).