# Bug with Moq It.IsAny<T>() when used with Extract Variable refactoring?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, lambda, moq

Can the `It.IsAny<T>()` argument matcher be initialized outside of a `mock.Verify(...)` lambda? It looks like Moq doesn't work properly if you extract the `It.IsAny<T>()` value into a variable (or a parameter).

I've been hunting all over the internet to see if there is a restriction on only using the `It` class from within a verify lambda, but I don't see that listed anywhere as a restriction.

I think both of tests should pass, but the second one fails:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Moq;

namespace MoqItIsAnyBug
{
    public interface ITest
    {
        void Foo(object value);
    }

    [TestClass]
    public class MoqItIsAnyBugTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void GivenInlineItIsAny_WhenVerify_ThenPasses()
        {
            var testMock = new Mock<ITest>();

            testMock.Object.Foo(new object());

            testMock.Verify(f => f.Foo(It.IsAny<object>()), Times.Once);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void GivenExtractedItIsAny_WhenVerify_ThenFails()
        {
            var testMock = new Mock<ITest>();

            testMock.Object.Foo(new object());

            var itIsAnyObject = It.IsAny<object>();
            testMock.Verify(f => f.Foo(itIsAnyObject), Times.Once);
            // Fails with: Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times: f => f.Foo(.itIsAnyObject)
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using Moq 4.2.1510.2205 from NuGet (dated 10/22/2015) and Visual Studio 2013.

Any ideas for a workaround?

---

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17053064/what-is-the-difference-between-passing-it-isanyint-and-the-value-of-it-isany) is the same question asked differently, with the answer as to "why".

Comment: `but the second one fails` can you clarify what you mean by fails? Is it just the `Verify` fails (I *think* this is probably what you mean)? Or does it not compile? Give a runtime error? What message is it actually giving you?

Comment: Thanks Matt, that is indeed the same question but it didn't turn up in my research. I've linked to it at the bottom of the question to try and drive more searches to the excellent answer there. I've also voted to mark as duplicate.