# How can I use It.IsAny as a parameter?

Tags: c#, moq

I have a test class invoking a mock of `MyClass`, I've `Setup` both `DoStuffA` and `DoStuffB` previously.

I've tried to wrap several `Verify` calls within a method, like so:

```
void VerifyMany(int input)
{
    _myClassMock.Verify(ic => ic.DoStuffA(input), Times.Once());
    _myClassMock.Verify(ic => ic.DoStuffB(input), Times.Once());
}
```

If I call my method with `It.IsAny<int>()` as the input - `VerifyMany(It.IsAny<int>())` - my tests don't pass, it will however work if I call the Verify method directly with It.IsAny:

```
_myClassMock.Verify(ic => ic.DoStuffA(It.IsAny<int>()), Times.Once());
_myClassMock.Verify(ic => ic.DoStuffB(It.IsAny<int>()), Times.Once());
```

I understand from the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17053064/what-is-the-difference-between-passing-it-isanyint-and-the-value-of-it-isany) question that Moq handles It.IsAny differently within an expression when specified to Setup/Verify, is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Could you share also the invocation of the metod?

Comment: to avoid confusion, either state that you are handling the `.Setup` prior to calling `VerifyMany` or provide it in your sample.  it seems, it "will" or "will not" work is not so determinable. I has caused confusion on what your attempting to get to work here.

Comment: @BrettCaswell Added some clarifications.

Comment: there is an underline problem with that question you linked actually.. just because It.IsAny<int> evaluates to 0 doesn't mean it wasn't still viable for his verify call, instead of passing 123 in verify, that OP should have just used `myValue`.  if you passed a variable into your mock, then you should verify using that variable as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work:

```
void VerifyMany(int input)
{
    _myClassMock.Verify(ic => ic.DoStuffA(input), Times.Once());
    _myClassMock.Verify(ic => ic.DoStuffB(input), Times.Once());
}
```

Is because `It.IsAny<int>()` (when simply invoked) returns 0. So essentially when `VerifyMany` is called with `It.IsAny<int>()`, you're passing 0 to `VerifyMany`. Which in turn means `DoStuffA(0)` and `DoStuffB(0)` are verified (not Any integer value as you probably intended it).

The other invocation:

```
_myClassMock.Verify(ic => ic.DoStuffA(It.IsAny<int>()), Times.Once());
_myClassMock.Verify(ic => ic.DoStuffB(It.IsAny<int>()), Times.Once());
```

Does work because the `ic => ic.DoStuffA(It.IsAny<int>()` part is never directly invoked. It is turned into an Expression Tree and Moq only walks (or visits if you like) that Expression Tree. Which means it will find `It.IsAny<int>()` in the Expression Tree and is then able to verify a call to `DoStuffA` (which it also found in the same expression tree) with any integer value. (for more on expression trees, feel free to [read this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/))

You could make this semi-work by creating a method which abstracts the call to `Verify` away and accepts an expression like so:

```
void VerifyOnce(Expression<Action<ClassMockIsBasedOn>> callToVerify)
{
    _myClassMock.Verify(callToVerify, Times.Once());
}
```

Which allows you to call that like so:

```
VerifyOnce(ic => ic.DoStuffA(It.IsAny<int>())
```

You could also extend the `VerifyOnce` example to accept multiple expressions. That would allow you to verify `DoStuffA` and `DoStuffB` on a single line:

```
void VerifyOnce(params Expression<Action<ClassMockIsBasedOn>>[] callsToVerify)
{
    foreach(var callToVerify in callsToVerify) 
    {
        _myClassMock.Verify(callToVerify, Times.Once());
    }
}
```

That would allow a call like so:

```
VerifyOnce(ic => ic.DoStuffA(It.IsAny<int>(),
           ic => ic.DoStuffB(It.IsAny<int>());
```

And of course you could replace `ClassMockIsBasedOn` with a generic. And add an overload which allows for methods which return values (instead of being void) or accept more than one parameter as Brett suggested in the comments.

Comment: could improve your abstract call with generics: `void VerifyOnce<T>(Expression<Action<T>> callToVerify)` would be usable here.  also `void VerifyOnce<TFrom, TTo>(Expression<Func<TFrom,TTo>> callToVerify)` as an overload. Though, you might have to add contraints and/or supply the types when calling to remove ambiguity.

Comment: I could pass the expression as a parameter, however I won't be able to perform two different MyClass methods with the same expression.

Comment: @JohnoBoy I think Vincent was providing an example of passing an expression and utilize it in a `.Verify` call, but you could just pass an array of expressions and loop through them with a foreach.. `IEnumerable<Action<ClassMockIsBasedOn>> callsToVerify` ...

Comment: Completely agree with Brett here, I'll expand the answer with an example

Answer (score 4):

`It.IsAny` only allows Moq to match future invocations of method calls if used within the `Setup` construct, you can't do it with `Verify` or `Assert` if your `Setup` isn't set `It.IsAny` yet. Because `It.IsAny` always return a default value of input.

So if you want to use `It.IsAny` at `Verify` you should `Setup` for target method first:

**Correct**

```
_myClassMock.Setup(ic => ic.DoStuffA(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(// Something here);
_myClassMock.Verify(ic => ic.DoStuffA(It.IsAny<int>()), Times.Once());
```

**Wrong**

```
_myClassMock.Setup(ic => ic.DoStuffA(1)).Returns(// Something here);
_myClassMock.Verify(ic => ic.DoStuffA(It.IsAny<int>()), Times.Once());
```

Comment: Could you elaborate this, why it cannot be used with `Verify`?

Comment: this answer is actually out of scope to what this question is about.  OP is essentially asking for a way to pass `Is.IsAny<int>` to his `VerifyMany` question, and have it evaluate properly.  @JohnoBoy should have stated he was doing the `.Setup` in another function scope or provided that in his sample to avoid confusion that lead to this answer.

Comment: To add: as @BrettCaswell mentioned, I've setup my mock previously.  
However, even if I didn't setup DoStuff with It.IsAny before, I'd still be able to Verify it with IsAny. I've tested this.